# Placing multiple cells into a single cell

Tags: matlab, cell

I have n number of cells that I want to place into a single cell. For instance, if n=24, I could just type of all 24 cells like so:

```
P={cell2mat(S.A1),cell2mat(S.A2),cell2mat(S.A3),...,cell2mat(S.A24)};
```

Clearly typing out like this is silly. What would be a better way of doing this? Maybe creating a loop? Also, in some cases I may have a different n, which makes the manual method that much more unappealing. Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Consecutive variable names like `A1` to `A24` are typically a bad idea, probably replacing all 24 with a single cell `S.A` is the simplest solution.

Comment: Why is that typically a bad idea? Inflexibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows.

```
 % some example S
    S.A1 = {[1, 2, 3]};
    S.A2 = {[3, 4, 5]};
    S.A3 = {[5, 6, 7]};



    n = 3; 


    one_cell = arrayfun(@(i) cell2mat(getfield(S, ['A',int2str(i)])), [1:n], 'UniformOutput', 0)


    one_cell{:}
    %
    % gives:
    %
    ans =

     1     2     3


    ans =

     3     4     5


    ans =

     5     6     7
```